# Folder select dialog buttons not working unless you select inside the folder first

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a little python script that helps me automate some simple tasks and one of the tasks requires me to select a directory to act on. So I'm using Tkinter to create a folder select dialog box. The problem I'm having is that when the dialog comes up selecting the buttons doesn't do anything until I select a folder in the view or one of the address or search bars. Basically it seems that selecting the buttons won't register as the window is not active? But if I activate the window by selecting a file in the view the buttons work.

Below is the function that has the folder select dialog. I should also say I'm using Windows 10.

Thanks!

```
def copy_project_template_folder():
    src_folder = r'A:\Projects\000_Project Template Folder'

    # Get the text from the clipboard
    clipboard_text = pyperclip.paste().strip()

    # Assign the main project directory in case clipboard isn't a directory
    ProjTargetDir = 'A:\Projects'

    # Check if the clipboard text is a valid directory
    if os.path.isdir(clipboard_text):
        ProjTargetDir = clipboard_text

    # Show the folder selection dialog to choose the destination folder
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    dst_folder = filedialog.askdirectory(title='Select Destination Folder', initialdir=ProjTargetDir)
    if not dst_folder:
        return  # User canceled the dialog

    # Copy all files and subdirectories in the source folder to the destination folder
    for item_name in os.listdir(src_folder):
        item_path = os.path.join(src_folder, item_name)
        dst_path = os.path.join(dst_folder, item_name)
        if os.path.isdir(item_path):
            shutil.copytree(item_path, dst_path)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(item_path, dst_folder)

    # Show a notification when the action is completed
    message = f'Project template folder copied successfully to "{dst_folder}"!'
    toaster = ToastNotifier()
    toaster.show_toast('Macro Launcher', message, duration=5, threaded=True)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code.

Comment: Ok, code has been indented but that's not the problem with the code. It's properly indented it just didn't indent properly when pasted on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I know it's not the problem with the code, but it's a problem _we_ have with the code. It's impossible for us to know how the code works, since indentation in python is critical to how it works. For example, I might not have guessed that all of the code is inside a single function. It's a bit unusual to create a root window the way  you do.